# Rails 3 MongoID and nested forms (embedded documents) - how to add form fields of fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-forms

I am using mongoid (3.0) and rails 3.2 to create a form that stores a model with multiple addresses. How can I add form fields on demand (since I want to let the user decide how much addresses to add to a model)?

In the "new" controller, i use @person.addresses.build to create the embedded document, everything works as expected, even if I try to add several addresses via the Rails console. But how can I create a dynamic form that adds nested fields on user request?

the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :title %>
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |t| %>
    this is an address input:
    <%= t.input :foo %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

the models:

```
class Rootobject
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title
  embeds_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Person < Rootobject
  field :firstname
end

class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :foo
  embedded_in :rootobject, :inverse_of => :addresses
end
```

The above code is simplified from what i am trying to do. My address form actually is in a partial. What would be the most simple way to make the nested form of addresses display another iteration (partial)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: go through this http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast this link will help you with your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/). It creates blueprint of address partial in which you can add <kbd>Add</kbd> **/** <kbd>Remove</kbd> buttons to add / remove address.